# How to select the whole week in tempus dominus bootstrap 4?

Tags: tempus-dominus-datetimepicker

Is it possible to select the whole week of a chosen day in bootstrap datetimepicker? What is a possible way to do so?

Comment: Did you get it working? I need this and i think it's not possible with this datepicker.